# why formatting input output requires variable to be supplied?

Tags: c, io, formatting, printf

I have just tried to know the output without supplying the variable instead just %d and there is no error in compiling the program but i wonder how the output displayed like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d");    
    return 0;
}
```

The output became 7288368

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: depending on compiler and the warning flags you set the above may pop out as a warning.

Comment: GIGO. Garbage in garbage out.

Answer (score 0):

> *"why formatting input output requires variable to be supplied?"*

Because the implementation of `printf` demands so. From the [manual page of `printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

*"Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %, and ends with a conversion specifier... The arguments **must** correspond properly (after type promotion) with the conversion specifier."*

You have used `"%d"` format string, which expects a integral argument appropriate for decimal conversion, yet you haven't provided any arguments, which resulted in an ***undefined behavior***